# Adding a Python list into the middle of an already populated CSV

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

I am generating a list of phone numbers from a registry into a Python list. I would then like to iterate through this list and add it to a new column in the middle of an already existing CSV file. The column is index 9 in the CSV. Below is the code I have attempted to write, but I get a "list index out of range error".

```
import csv

with open('input.csv','r') as csvinput:
    with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
        i=0
        for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
            row[9]=writer.writerow(phone_list[i])
            i+=1


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-74ca13edafc8> in <module>()
      6         i=0
      7         for row in csv.reader(csvinput):
----> 8             row[9]=writer.writerow(phone_list[i])
      9             i+=1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to your first question on StackOverflow. This code snippet is not complete, since you do not show us the `input.csv` file. You also do not show the full traceback for the error message. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should almost work, you can use `zip()` to iterate over the input file and the list of phones at the same time, instead of using the `i` variable as a numerical index:

```
for row, phone in zip(csv.reader(csvinput), phone_list):
    row[9] = phone
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Now, if you're still getting that `IndexError`, that means your csv file has some line that doesn't contain 10 columns in first place (index 9 is the 10th column since indexes start at 0). Double-check your csv file. Try this testing code to check:

```
for row, phone in zip(csv.reader(csvinput), phone_list):
    if len(row) < 10:
         print('FOUND A ROW WITH {} COLUMNS: '.format(len(row)), row)
    else:
         row[9] = phone
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Another solution is to add empty columns to complete the 10 columns to every row that has less than 10 columns:

```
for row, phone in zip(csv.reader(csvinput), phone_list):
    row.extend(['']* (10 - len(row)))
    row[9] = phone
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Beat me to it! Now I have to delete all I typed!

Comment: If I may add, if the row has less than 10 columns, then you can use `row.append(phone)`

Comment: I still receive the following error, even though my file most definitely has ten columns.

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-02dc15177d18> in <module>()
      1 for row, phone in zip(csv.reader('input.csv'), phone_list):
----> 2     row[9] = phone
      3     writer.writerow(row)

IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: @CheerSal I added code to check the csv file at the end of my answer, can you run it to make sure this isn't the problem? Also, can you please edit the question and  add the full error traceback?

Comment: @CheerSal now I added example code to complete the number of columns to 10 when you have less than 10 columns.

Comment: FOUND A ROW WITH 1 COLUMNS:  ['/']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-8c97f9716210> in <module>()
      4     else:
      5          row[9] = phone
----> 6     writer.writerow(row)

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: @CheerSal That means your csv file does have a row with a single column, or you're reading the wrong file. Also, if you put that code outside the `with` statement for the output file, it will be already closed. Make sure to put that code **inside** the `with open('output.csv', 'w')`  block.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, add the new column to the array 'row', then write that row to the csv.

```
for row in reader:
     row.insert(9, phone_list[i])
     writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: 'str' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: import csv

    with open('input.csv','r') as reader:
        with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
            writer = csv.writer(csvoutput)
            i=0
                for row in reader:
                row.insert(9, phone_list[i])
                writer.writerow(row)
                i+=1'

Comment: If that's the code your using, you haven't created a csv reader or writer object, only file objects

Comment: with open('input.csv','r') as reader: with open('output.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:

Comment: No, you need to make a csv.reader() object and point that to your file object, you have made already made a csv.writer() object

Comment: This did it! Thanks for the help

Comment: Good, no worries

Answer (score 0):

if you are using anaconda, or have knowledge of pandas,

```
import pandas as pd.  # You import the pandas library

input = pd.read_csv("input.csv") #your import csv
output = pd.read_csv("output.csv") #your export csv

input_array = list(input['#Name of column']) #use this if you know the name of the column
input_array = list(input.iloc[:,#index of column]) # use this if you know the index number of the column, index starts from 0

output = output.insert(loc=#the index you want; in this case 9 for the 10th column, column='Name of the new column', value=input_array) # you are inserting the array into output.csv

output.to_csv("path and output.csv",index = False) # we are writing a file, index = false means no new index row columns to be added.





import pandas as pd.  # You import the pandas library

input = pd.read_csv("input.csv") #your import csv
output = pd.read_csv("output.csv") #your export csv

input_array = list(input['Name of column']) #use this if you know the name of the column
input_array = list(input.iloc[:,0]) # Assuming input csv has only 1 column

output = output.insert(loc=9, column='New_column_name', value=input_array) # assuming the array is to be inserted into output.csv, column 10, in which case its 9 in pandas

output.to_csv("path and output.csv",index = False) # we are writing a file, index = false means no new index row columns to be added.
```

Comment: Could you include an example of code that would be inserted? I am having trouble understanding your parameters?

Comment: Okay, so this is a csv being imported into a csv. I need a list inserted into a csv

Comment: If your Input.csv file has the list of numbers that you need to be put into output.csv. The line with input_array converts the input.csv file into a list. Which you add to output.csv if you already have a list, just put it into value, on the line with output.insert.

Comment: No, I have a list that is not in a csv file. It is a Python list

Comment: But you did understand my explanation right? You can insert the list you created into output.csv with code in the line which has output.insert, where it says value put in your list